# How can I troubleshoot keybindings on Ventura? (loading, validating, defining...)

Tags: ventura, keybindings

I have an older Mac that could only upgrade to Catalina. I have a DefautlKeyBinding.dict file that worked fine on it that let me redefine how the Home and End keys were used. (Included at the bottom of this question.) I've tried this same file on two Mac Minis running Ventura (one is using 13.3.1, the other 13.5.2) and I'm finding the key bindings on them aren't working like they do on the old iMac.

I'm not sure why this file isn't working. (You can see I've added in one test to try to test it - and with that extra definition in there, it's still not responding.)

While a simple answer of, "Do this and it'll work," would be great, I'd also like to find out:

1. Is there a way to validate a keybinding file to be sure it'll work?
2. How can I reload a keybinding file without rebooting my Mac? (Or does each app load the files when launching?)
3. Is there a log somewhere that'll tell me if the keybinding loaded properly or not?

```
{
/* Remap Home / End keys to be correct */
"\UF729"   = moveToBeginningOfLine:                       ;/*           Home */
"\UF72B"   = moveToEndOfLine:                             ;/*            End */
"$\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:     ;/*     Shift+Home */
"$\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:           ;/*      Shift+End */
"@\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfDocument:                   ;/*       Cmd+Home */
"@\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfDocument:                         ;/*.       Cmd+End */
"$@\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection: ;/* Shift+Cmd+Home */
"$@\UF72B" = moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:       ;/*  Shift+Cmd+End */
/* "\UF739" = (insertText:, "Testing text to see if anything works."); */
}
```